# Is there an enumeration for field properties on Field creation?

Tags: csom, caml, custom-field-types

I want to create a CAML for creating fields. There are some properties that could be different. So the XML at the end looks something like this:

```
void CreateField(string name, bool isCharacter, bool hasCommas, string type) {
  string xml=$"<Field Type='{type}' Name='{name}'";
  if (isCharacter) {
     xml+=" MaxLength='1'";
  }
  if (!hasCommas) {
    xml+="Commas='FALSE'";
  }
  xml+=">";
  list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(xml, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
}
```

(I reduced the complexety of the example to make it better readable)

While this works, I would prefer not working with strings, where it isn't required. So instead of "Commas" I would like to use an enumeration `FieldCondition.Commas`, instead of MaxLength `FieldCondition.MaxLength` and so on.

While I could create an Enumeration for this by myself (and will, if there is no better way) I wonder if there is already an enumeration hidden somewhere in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`-namespace containing exactly those values I could use?

Comment: It seems simple enough to take a list of values, and join them on comma. What hidden complexity am I missing, here?

Answer (score 0):

`XmlSerializer` can be used to create a field xml. Create a class to represent the field object with properties Name, Type, MaxLength etc. Use that class in XmlSerializer. The sample code is below.

```
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type {get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int MaxLength {get; set;}
} 

//Fill up the Field object
Field f = new Field();
f.Type = "Text";
f.Name = "fieldName";
f.MaxLength = 256;

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Field));
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    xws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriter xw = (XmlWriter)XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, xws);

    //Remove namespaces in the output
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    //Add an empty namespace and empty value
    ns.Add("", "");

    //Serialize Field object to xml
    xs.Serialize(xw, f, ns);
    Response.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}

//Sample output
//<Field Type="Text" Name="fieldName" MaxLength="256" />
```